# Extracting azure environment to go on-premise

Tags: azure

For an assignment from school I need to build a small network in Microsoft Azure. But i also need to research how (and if) it works to move out of Azure. I searched the internet and can't find that much about this topic.

Situation:
1 vnet
2 subnets (DMZ and Backend)
3 Webserver and Jumpserver in de DMZ
4 Database (connected to the webserver) in the backend
5 Two NSG's for the DMZ and the backend

Now my question is. What is the procedure if i wanted to extract this network (servers, database, all data everything!) out of azure to an on-premise situation. What are the costs? What do i need to do? How long will it take?

Comment: You need to try something, we are not consultants who discover your environment and manage the project for you. How long of a downtime window is available? What cloud services need to be converted into something else? What is the design of the new network? What backups are available to restore? What is the cost of Internet egress and upgrading to faster links?

Comment: Look at Azure recovery vault.  You install an appliance on-premise and replicate the servers down into that environment the same way you would use the recovery vault to replicate on-prem servers into Azure.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-recovery-services-vault-overview